# Stylesheet version not showing in browser when adding version number to stylesheet in enqueue

Tags: wp-enqueue-style

I'm trying to figure out why I'm not seeing the stylesheet version number is my browser, when I add the version number to the enqueue function, where I enqueue the stylesheet.

Here's the code:

```
wp_enqueue_style('sage/main.css', asset_path('styles/main.css'), array(), '1111111' );
```

Using the version number '1111111' just to test.

When I inspect in my browser, I still see the stylesheet without a version number (client name obscured for privacy):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" id="sage/main.css-css" href="http://localhost:8000/wp-content/themes/XXXX/dist/styles/main.css" type="text/css" media="all">
```

The styles are loading and everything else is correct, just missing the version number. What am I missing?

(This is a laravel site.)

Comment: If it's a Laravel site why (and how) are you using a WordPress function `wp_enqueue_style()`?

Comment: Hey @JacobPeattie, great question. I found this resource online that explains how to integrate laravel with wordpress: https://wpengine.com/resources/wordpress-laravel/

Comment: As best I can guess, you're using Acorn and Corcel in your theme in order to use Laravel *within* WordPress?

Comment: @bosco hm, I think a lot of people are getting stuck on the fact that it's a laravel site. I only mention it to explain the use of asset_path(), but the code in question -  wp_enqueue_style is a wordpress function, and can be understood by someone who's not familiar with laravel.

Answer (score 1):

It appears you're using the Sage theme framework - presumably you're also using Soil? One of Soil's modules explicitly disables asset versioning - ensure that you haven't enabled in it in your theme by way of

```php
add_theme_support( 'soil-disable-asset-versioning' );
```

or

```php
add_theme_support( 'soil', [ 'disable-asset-versioning' ] );
```

If Soil is not responsible it could be any number of other plugins - in particular any sort of caching/optimization plugin.